# redirect site to WWW except Api routes

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all routes of my site to www.mysite.com
This is my Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.xxx .com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but I want to use API routes without WWW prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your RewriteRule line to this

```
RewriteRule ^((?!api).*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

The pattern **((?!api).*)** means to match any uri but **api** . This means that http://example.com/api will not get redirected to http://www.example.com/api .